# ZoomIn ZoomOut Fancy box

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

When i click on image it comes big, if i click on it, then it zooms in, It must be zoomed in even if i click next or previos button until i zoom Out, This must not use the zoom button in toolbar, i need it in image when it is displayed when i click, i was working today half found some solution, but it was not i needed.
Please Help...

Find my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.5/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<!-- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.5/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.5/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<!-- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.5/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js -->

</head>
<body>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://buddhisteconomics.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/hdwp693968124.jpg">
  <img src="https://buddhisteconomics.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/hdwp693968124.jpg" width="150" height="150">
</a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg" width="150" height="150">
</a>
<input type="hidden" name="zoomBTN" value="0" id="zoomBTN">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 /*$(document).ready(funtion(){
  
 });*/
 /*$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  // Options will go here
  toolbar  : false,
  smallBtn : true,
  iframe : {
   preload : false
  }
 });*/

 $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
     // Options will go here
     toolbar  : false,
     smallBtn : true,
     iframe : {
         preload : false
     },clickContent: function(current, event) {
     var getExistval = $("#zoomBTN").val();
     $(".fancybox-image").click(function(){
         if(getExistval == 0){
             $("#zoomBTN").val('1');
         } else if(getExistval == 1){
             $("#zoomBTN").val('0');
         } else {
             $("#zoomBTN").val('1');
         }
     });
     return current.type === "image" ? "zoom" : false;
   },afterShow :function() {
     if($("#zoomBTN").val() == 1){
         $('.fancybox-button--zoom').click();
     }
   }

 });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is currently no option to open images in full size on start; this feature will be implemented in next major version (https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1343)

Comment: Thanks for that, i hv done that....But it took lot of time. check the updated code

Comment: btw, you can do `instance.scaleToActual();` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzBJqM?editors=1010